# R code + text: Differences in code chunk delimitation between Rmd and R

Tags: html, pdf, knitr, chunks

I am starting to embed R codes with text and I'm using `knitr` to generate pdf and html documents. I've already done that before by editing Rmarkdown files, but it seems to me that there's an advantage of [compiling reports directly from R scripts](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html) (instead of from Rmarkdown files): it is much easier to run the R code itself in an `.R` document, and test it, to after that be able to add text and print it in a beaultiful and presentable fashion.

However, I noticed there is a difference in how code chunks are defined when using Rmd or R directly.

In Rmarkdown, to delimit a code chunk I need to set where it starts (it is denoted by ```` ```{r} ````) and when it ends (which is denoted by ```` ``` ````). Everything between these two elements corresponds to R code and comments, that will be read as code in a single chunk.

When compiling the reports directly from R code, however, I can delimit when a chunk starts (by typing `#+` or `#-` or anything like `#---`, according to the function [spin](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/), used to render the documents) but I do not set where the chunk ends (and I did not find information about that, yet). I assume that, in this notation, a code chunk automatically ends if another chunk is set to begin (through `#+`, for instance) or if something is set to be compiled as text (through `#'` in the beginning of the line). Otherwise, I would assume everything in the script is considered as the same code chunk.

Am I right about these assumptions?
Is there a way of explicitly stating that a code chunk has to end when compiling reports from R scripts?

Thanks in advance,
Bernardo

Comment: Does this web page,  https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html, answer your question?  It's not clear what you're asking.  Perhaps if you post a reproducible example?

Comment: I agree with @user2554330 that the question is rather unclear. But please have a look at [`read_chunk()`](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/), as this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello @user2554330, I am sorry, I still new to StackOverflow. I re-stated my question (and even the title), do you think it is clearer now? Thanks for the link, I had already visited it by I did not pay attention to the function spin, that presents some more information about when a code chunk is set to begin. I used that to re-state my question.

Comment: @CL., thanks for the link, but I think this is not what I was looking for. `read_chunk()` may be used to read chunks from external scripts (what may be a solution for clearly delimiting where it starts and ends, indeed), but I was wondering how I could delimit the beginning and end of the chunk in a single R script (so that I keep the advantage of being able to run a whole analysis using only one R script - not many scripts nor one file with the code separated, as in .Rmd files). Is my point clear or I messed it again? (Sorry in advance in this case!)

Comment: If my question is still unclear, please let me know so I'll think about an example.

Comment: I still don't understand the issue.  Why does it matter to you whether several lines of code are in one chunk or two?

Comment: Hi @user2554330, it is important for since I want to change the options for each chunk. For some of them I want to see only the resulting figures (in different sizes depending on the figure), for others I may also want to print the results, the error messages, or the warnings. Then, it would be good to make sure until where a certain set of local chunk options apply, so that the output report show exactly what I want for each code chunk. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Anyway, from lots of tests I did here, it seems that my assumptions are correct...

Comment: I think your assumptions *are* correct. If I have the time I'll add a more detailed answer later.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question. It has taken me a long time to figure things out, I worked a little tonight.

a '#+' delimiter begins a section than can only be code.  blank lines are ok, R-style comments are ok, but any #' style encoding for markdown will terminate the chunk.  Any default chunk options will revert to default after embedded rmarkdown encoding.

I have an example coded if there's still interest in this.

Comment: The example would be welcomed!